# add_cuda_library outputing: Unresolved extern function

Tags: python, c++, cmake, cuda, pybind11

I am trying to compile a few .cu source files into a python module. Which works fine as long as there is not more than one file.
The CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
find_package(CUDA)
find_package(PythonLibs 3.7 REQUIRED)
find_package(pybind11)

file(GLOB_RECURSE sources ${SRC}/launcher.cu)

cuda_add_library(main SHARED ${SRC}/module.cpp ${sources})
target_link_libraries(main ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} cudart)
set_target_properties(main PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPERABLE_COMPILATION ON)
```

The above file will compile a python module neatly

But when `${sources}` contains several .cu file, the linking just doesn't happen. I receive the following error:

> ```
> [ 16%] Building NVCC (Device) object
> CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/main_generated_launcher.cu.o ptxas fatal   :
> Unresolved extern function '_ZN5StateIdE16WithinBoundariesEii'
> CMake Error at main_generated_launcher.cu.o.cmake:279 (message):
>  Error generating file
>  [...]/DNA_PredatorPrey/build/CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/./main_generated_launcher.cu.o
> ```

The "Unresolved extern function points" is a function that the linker is supposed to find in another source file.

When using `add_executable(....)` instead of `cuda_add_library` on the exact same group of files, it will compile into a working executable file.

So I'm looking for what `cuda_add_library` requires in order to link files properly.

Comment: I know it is a trivial check, but I think it is worth asking. In your not working example with multiple files, have you specified the files directly in the `cuda_add_library` or were you populating a variable with filenames with some `GLOB_RECURSE` and then you used this one inside the `cuda_add_library` call? I'm just trying to cancel any chance it is a problem not related to cuda management (e.g. a missing file or a wrong filepath)

Comment: @albestro I tried writing the filenames inside the cuda_add_library to no avail

Comment: Can you try specifying files before the `SHARED` keyword inside the `cuda_add_library` call? e.g `cuda_add_library(main file1 file2 SHARED)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned you are using directly `LANGUAGES CUDA`. You may just use `add_library()` instead of `add_cuda_library()` as it is supported by cmake as an first languague. I guess some project using older version cmake(<3.8?) would need something like `CUDA_ADD_LIBRARY CUDA_ADD_EXECUTABLE`. But as a first language, you can just regard it as a normal c project.

Comment: Being able to use the normal add_library solved so many problems for me. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

Linking to cuda libraries this way is not necessary anymore. You can probably use the `enable_language(CUDA)`, which will take care of the linking.

You can have a look at [this tutorial](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/chapters/packages/CUDA.html) or this example from [Nvidia dev blogs](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/building-cuda-applications-cmake/)

Comment: Can you be more specific when you say "Linking to cuda libraries this way is not necessary anymore"?
I had already enabled the CUDA language with this command:

project(ProjectName LANGUAGES CUDA CXX)

Comment: You say it is not necessary, but there's probably something necessary that I am not doing.
Thank you for the tutorial and the example, I read both and I really don't see what I am missing